# Mod rewrite doesn't work on SSL

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Here is my rewrite code:

```
## File Security
<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess)$">
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

#### Apache directory listing rules ####
DirectoryIndex index.php index.htm index.html
IndexIgnore *

#### Rewrite rules for SEO functionality ####

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.genyx.co.uk/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html?$ index.php?seo_path=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

But it doesn't work on SSL pages, for example:

http://www.genyx.co.uk/terms-and-conditions.html

and

https://www.genyx.co.uk/terms-and-conditions.html

Can someone help me make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit:

http://www.genyx.co.uk/   -> shows some content

https://www.genyx.co.uk/  -> shows the default Apache site "It works!"

So the SSL server has a different DocumentRoot. If you change this it should work as expected.

By the way, please check your SSL certificates. I would assume that you have to add intermediate certificates or some of your visitors will get warnings that the site is not signed by a trusted instance.

Edit: You can [check by yourself](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.genyx.co.uk%2F) if everything is fine with your SSL server or if the certificate chain is incomplete.

Edit 2:

Your certificate provider has a nice description about [intermediate certificates](http://www.globalsign.com/support/intermediate/about-intermediates.php). And [here](http://www.globalsign.com/support/intermediate/domainssl_intermediate2011.php) is the place to download it. See below how you can install this in relation to the already installed certificate file.

```
# Apache configuration for specific virtual host ...
# start SSL/TLS
SSLEngine on
# set signed certificate file
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain_certificate.crt
# set private key file
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain_certifikate.key
# set intermediate certificate / to complete the chain to the root certificate
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/chain_certificate.crt
```

Comment: Hi, I have seen that you have finally solved the problem with your mod_rewrite. Unfortunately you had ignored my hint regarding the missing link in your SSL certificate chain. Anyway I have added in above answer the links to a good description about the problem and how to solve it. If you still do not believe wait a little some of your clients will get warnings about a not trusted certificate. It depends on the clients browser and version.

Comment: Hello,Sorry I hired someone to solve the problem because it was really urgent. I am now working on the SLL errors.
What is a certificate chain?

Comment: I have linked a good description about this (see Edit 2). In short your certification provider hasn't used the root certificate which is installed in all browsers to sign your certificate. So you have to add an intermediate to make your certificate working on all browsers. Details are attached in section Edit 2 as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would review where these rules are placed. I suspect you might have them in a virtual host section or some other place that your SSL vHost isn't matching.

Comment: Thanks, I'll get someone to look into that!